# Sum of an arithmetic series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a_1, a_2, ..., a_{n-1}$ is strictly positive, not equal, real numbers

If  $a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_{n-1}$ = $n-1$. Then what will be the answer for

$\frac{n}{\frac{1}{a_1} + \frac{1}{a_2}+ ... + \frac{1}{a_{n-1}}}$

I know it's an elementary but a bit difficult for me to catch it

Comment: The answer could be anything, it's not unique.

Comment: Which numbers are allowed? Real, rational, positive?

Comment: It is real numbers

Comment: Or is it possible to show that the answer could be less than 1.

Comment: plus they are strictly positive numbers but not all equal

Comment: @Dereje update the OP with this limitation for $a_i\ge 0$ to make your question more clear.

Comment: @gimusi yes  you are right and I did that

Comment: You write in the title "arithmetic series", yet in the question you write "Strictly positive real numbers"...which one is it? For the last one you already have an answer that shows no unique answer exists...

Comment: @Dereje Can you please add all the details to your question? Your question should have all the information, not the comments.

Comment: @TobyMak I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for $a_i\ge 0$ by **[HM-AM](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Root-Mean_Square-Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean-Harmonic_mean_Inequality)** inequality we have that

$$\frac{n-1}{\frac{1}{a_1} + \frac{1}{a_2}+ ... + \frac{1}{a_{n-1}}}\le \frac{a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_{n-1}
}{n-1}=1$$

then we can bound the expression by

$$\frac{n}{\frac{1}{a_1} + \frac{1}{a_2}+ ... + \frac{1}{a_{n-1}}}\le \frac{n}{n-1}$$

In general we can't find a closed expression for its value.

Answer (score 0):

With $n = 2$, $a_1+a_2 = 1$. If $a_1 = x, a_2 = 1-x$, then:
$$\frac{2}{\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{1-x}} = \frac{2x(1-x)}{(1-x)+x} = 2x(1-x) = -2x^2+2x.$$

The maximum has x-coordinate $-\frac{b}{2a}$ or $-\frac{2}{2\cdot -2} = \frac{1}{2}$. Therefore, the maximum value is $-2 \cdot (\frac{1}{2})^2 + 2(\frac{1}{2}) = -\frac{1}{2} + 1 = \frac{1}{2}$. Therefore, the fraction is always less than $1$ for $n=2$.

Comment: How is the max x-coordinate becomes -4x + 2 =0 ? Isn't it -2x + 2 ?

Comment: @Dereje I took the derivative. I forgot there was an easier way, which is edited in the question. Note that this only works if $n=2$.

Comment: Do you think there is an easy way for n=3 ?

Comment: @Dereje For $n=3$ you can see gimusi's answer. It's actually quite good!

Comment: Yes actually, it is a good generalization.